# Маятник на Opengl

Tags: opengl, графика, физика

подскажите, пожалуйста, логику для реализации простого маятника. Как там физику считать?
Я - новичок в этом деле

Comment: `A*sin(w*t)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

ну есть же профильные ресурсы (типа википедии, хахаха)

математический маятник:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA

```
x = A * sin(w * t + a)
x^2 + y^2 = l^2
```

вот у вас есть формула малых колебаний маятника